# SQL - foreign key error

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I get this error when I try to add the foreign key :

> "ORA-00904: "BR_ID": invalid identifier"

```
create table Branch9
(br_id number NOT NULL,br_name varchar2(25) NOT NULL ,br_address varchar2(30),PRIMARY KEY(br_id))

create table Employee9
(emp_id number NOT NULL,emp_name varchar2(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,emp_address varchar2(30),emp_age number,emp_dob date,emp_salary number,PRIMARY KEY(emp_id))

ALTER TABLE Employee9
ADD FOREIGN KEY (br_id) REFERENCES Branch9 (br_id);
```

Is it anything related to `NOT NULL` constraint added to br_id?

Comment: The not null constraint on Branch9(br_id) is redundant, since it's a primary key, which cannot be null in oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`br_id` has to be in `Employee9` table:

This is how you add it:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee9 ADD br_id number NOT NULL;
```

Then you can do:

```
ALTER TABLE Employee9 
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_br_id FOREIGN KEY (br_id) REFERENCES Branch9 (br_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

br_id needs to be a column in Employee9.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `br_id` column in `Employee9`, is there?:

```
create table Employee9 (
    emp_id number NOT NULL,
    emp_name varchar2(25) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    emp_address varchar2(30),
    emp_age number,
    emp_dob date,
    emp_salary number,
    PRIMARY KEY(emp_id)
)
```